# Can you get the key of light on terraria pc

Tags: terraria

I got 20 souls of light and went to the guide to see what I could craft and it shows me the "Key of Light". I looked on the Terraria wiki and it said that you craft it at a regular crafting table, but it wouldn't give me the option to.

I really want the Daedalus Storm bow so I can fight Skeletron Prime, help please?

Comment: Did you remember to take the Souls of Light back from the Guide after checking what you could craft with them? Or did you move away and let them drop on the floor? I do that more often than I care to admit.

Comment: Soory I meant it doesnt show me

Comment: That sounds like the exact opposite of what your question is saying. You may want to edit it to clarify. If you're saying the Guide NPC doesn't mention the Key of Light when you ask about crafting recipes using Souls of Light: what version are you playing?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Guide shows that you can craft it, then yes, you definitely can craft it. Any problem with that is error on your part, such as not having enough Souls, or not being near a Workbench.